# expectations on all instances on JMockit

Tags: jmockit

I was expecting JMockit to set expectations on *all* instances. However, that does not work when I add a constructor expectation to the mix.

```
class Foo {
    Foo(int i) {}
    void foo() {}
}

@Test
public void expectationsOnAllInstances__Works(@Mocked Foo foo) {
    new Expectations() {{
        foo.foo();
    }};
    new Foo(3).foo();
}

@Test
public void expectationsOnAllInstances__DoesntWork(@Mocked Foo foo) {
    new Expectations() {{
        new Foo(3);  // <==== this constructor expectation messes things up ...
        foo.foo();
    }};
    new Foo(3).foo();
}
```

The second test fails with error:

```
Missing 1 invocation to:
Foo#foo()
   on mock instance: Foo@617faa95
instead got:
Foo#foo()
   on mock instance: Foo@1e127982
```

JMockit 1.48

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `expectationsOnAllInstances__DoesntWork` test is inconsistent between the expectations recorded and replayed...

What you really want is one of these two other versions:

```
    @Test
    public void expectationsOnAllInstances_consistent1(@Mocked Foo foo) {
        new Expectations() {{
            new Foo(3).foo();
        }};

        new Foo(3).foo();
    }

    @Test
    public void expectationsOnAllInstances_consistent2(@Mocked Foo foo) {
        new Expectations() {{
            new Foo(3);
            foo.foo();
        }};

        new Foo(3);
        foo.foo();
    }
```

Comment: I had always assumed that writing `new Expectations() {{... foo.foo();}}` meant to state that the `foo` method was to be called on _some_ instance, no matter which one (and no matter what was on the ellipsis).

Comment: Yes, but recording a constructor expectation on a `@Mocked` class changes that, so the test can match expectations to the specific instances created according to that constructor expectation.

Comment: @beluchin Besides, the proper way to verify expectations is with a `new Verifications() {...}` block at the end of the test. `Expectations` should only be used to record expected `result`s.